# How to save chainladder Triangle in Database

Tags: python, sql

is there a way to save chainladder Triangle in SQL Database in the following Format?

```
Origin-Year   Development-Year   Value
1988          12                 10535.3
1988          24                 20535.3
1988          36                 30535.3
1989          12                 40535.3
```

Trianlge

```
 1988   1989   1990   1991   1992   
 5930   4725   95050  13160  16510  
 NaN    933.0  5185   976.0  149.0  
 NaN    NaN    96.0   742.0  118964.0
 NaN    NaN    NaN    9517.0 73420.0
 NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    12479.0
 NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
```

[image]

Comment: Yes of course there is. Isn't this a simple set of rows in a very simple table?

Comment: no actually the triangle is not in this format . i'll upload the triangle as well for you!

Comment: Didn't think it could be that simple. Please upload the source as text rather than an image.

Comment: the triangle also has origin year on the left i just did'nt know how to write it in a proper format here in stack's box

Answer (score 1):

You can use pandas to reshape your data as well as send it to a database.

```
raa = cl.load_sample('raa')
long = raa.to_frame().unstack().reset_index().rename(
    columns={'level_0':'development',
             'level_1':'origin',
             0:'values'}).dropna()
long.to_sql(...)
```